# Python submitting webform using requests

Tags: python, webforms, urllib

So I need to crawl [this](http://www.justiceservices.gov.mt/courtservices/Judgements/search.aspx?func=selected) website using python, however I am finding a problem when trying to submit the form. The response I get is the same page with the form and not the result after submitting the form. I tried to use requests `library/ mechanize / urllib`.

The code with requests:

```
url = "http://www.justiceservices.gov.mt/courtservices/Judgements/search.aspx?func=selected"
payload = {'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$tb_date_from':'',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$tb_date_to':'',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$dd_court':108,
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$dd_judiciary':'',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$tb_litigant1':'',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$tb_litigant2':'',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$tb_keywords':'',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$keywords':'rb_keywords_matching_all',                    
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$bt_search':'Search',
           'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$search_selected_panel$result_count_panel$dd_result_count':10}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post(url,payload,allow_redirects=True)
print r.headers
print r.text
```

Do I need to post additional data? or my approach is wrong to the type of form. The website uses web-forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the requests source, specifically https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L80 you'll see that post ignores args. Without having time to test, it would seem likely you need to do:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, allow_redirects=True
```

Comment: nope :/ still nothing. I think Im leaving something out while sending the data. it is as if I am trying to submit an empty form

Comment: Having actually looked at the page, I think the problem is that there's no form there. It's not ever submitted and we can't tell where the data is actually posted to, the submit button on the form is handled by a js function, it's likely a post on that page does nothing

Comment: Yes it is old technology, I have to loop through the court options and submit the form. I know it is difficult but I have to do it for an assignment. I really have no idea how to do it

Comment: As I say, there's no form to submit, I guess you'd have to somehow call the js that's attached to the submit button.(I submitted a POST to that page (with all the fields filled in) and got back just the page, with none of the error messages generated when you submit the form without correct information manually)