# use python requests to post a html form to a server and save the reponse to a file

Tags: python

I have exactly the same problem as this post

[Python submitting webform using requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407580/python-submitting-webform-using-requests)

but your answers do not solve it. When I execute this HTML file called api.htm in the browser, then for a second or so I see its page.

Then the browser shows the data I want with the URL https://api.someserver.com/api/ as as per the action below. But I want the data written to a file so I try the Python 2.7 script below.

But all I get is the source code of api.htm Please put me on the right track!

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="ID" method="post" action="https://api.someserver.com/api/ ">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="passkey">
<input type="text" name="start" value ="2015-05-01">
<input type="text" name="end" value ="2015-05-31">
<input type="submit" value ="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("ID").submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code:

```
import urllib
import requests

def main():
    try:

    values = {'start' : '2015-05-01',
    'end' : '2015-05-31'}
    req=requests.post("http://my-api-page.com/api.htm",
    data=urllib.urlencode(values))
    filename = "datafile.csv"
    output = open(filename,'wb')
    output.write(req.text)
    output.close()
    return 

main()
```

Comment: Your post target doesn't match the `action` attribute of the server, and you are missing the `key` field.

Comment: Your Python code is also invalid; You'll need to remove the `try:` line at least. Don't use `urllib.urlencode(values)`; `data=values` is enough.

Comment: But the values are already hardcoded into the api.htm. I should not need the to get the result but included them for future flexibility. I removed the try and the line data=url... but trsult is the same.

Comment: "Your post target doesn't match the action attribute of the server,"

Comment: >>Your post target doesn't match the action attribute of the server,

If I knew a way of piping the browser output to a file, I would not need Python. As I wrote before the api.htm file is used to submit the data to the action target. But how can I harness the response?

Answer (score 0):

I can see several problems:

- Your post target URL is incorrect. The `form` `action` attribute tells you where to post to:

  ```html
  <form id="ID" method="post" action="https://api.someserver.com/api/ ">
  ```
- You are not including all the fields; `type=hidden` fields need to be posted too, but you are ignoring this one:

  ```html
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="passkey">
  ```
- Do not URL-encode your POST variables yourself; leave this to `requests` to do for you. By encoding yourself `requests` won't recognise that you are using an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type as the body. Just pass in the dictionary as the `data` parameters and it'll be encoded for you *and* the header will be set.

You can also *stream* the response straight to a file object; this is helpful when the response is large. Switch on response streaming, make sure the underlying raw `urllib3` file-like object decodes from transfer encoding and use `shutil.copyfileobj` to write to disk:

```
import requests
import shutil

def main():
    values = {
        'start': '2015-05-01',
        'end': '2015-05-31',
        'key': 'passkey',
    }
    req = requests.post("http://my-api-page.com/api.htm",
                        data=values, stream=True)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        with open("datafile.csv", 'wb') as output:
            req.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(req.raw, output)
```

There may still be issues with that `key` value however; perhaps the server sets a new value for each session, coupled with a cookie, for example. In that case you'd have to use a [`Session()` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to preserve cookies, first do a `GET` request to the `api.htm` page, parse out the `key` hidden field value and only **then** post. If that is the case then using a tool like [`robobrowser`](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) might just be easier.